# How to to reduce the Size of rich:Editor in jsf

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces, tinymce

This is the where i was working on. by default it is taking as a min height 100px which was defined in 'tinyjs file'. but without changing the tiny_mce.js file how can i achieve this in my jsf.

```
 <rich:editor id="PropDefValue_rich" theme="advanced" value="#{configIOTAttrController.i18nText.propertyValue}" required="true" width="750" height="50" rendered="#{not configIOTAttrController.plainText}" requiredMessage="The default value is required.">
      <f:param name="plugins" value="paste,table,safari"/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top"/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="left"/>
      <f:param name="forced_root_block" value=""/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons1" value="undo,redo,bold,italic,sub,sup,numlist,bullist,separator,link,unlink,outdent,indent,separator,charmap,separator,cleanup,code,separator,pasteword,pastetext"/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons2" value=""/>
      <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons3" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
setup : function(ed) {
  ed.onInit.add(function() { 
    var frameid = frameid ? frameid : tinymce.activeEditor.id+'_ifr';
    var currentfr = document.getElementById(frameid);
    currentfr.height = 10; // set height to 10px
  });
},
```

In jsf notification it should be something like (might be necessary to be written in one line):

```
 <f:param name="setup" value="    setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function() { 
        var frameid = frameid ? frameid : tinymce.activeEditor.id+'_ifr';
        var currentfr = document.getElementById(frameid);
        currentfr.height = 10;
      });
    },"/>
```

**EDIT:**

```
var frameid = frameid ? frameid : this.editor.id+'_ifr';
var currentfr=document.getElementById(frameid);

if (currentfr && !window.opera){
  currentfr.style.display="block";
  currentfr.height = 10;
  styles = currentfr.getAttribute('style').split(';');
  for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
    if ( styles[i].search('height:') ==1 ){
      styles.splice(i,1);
    break;
      }
  };
  currentfr.setAttribute('style', styles.join(';'));
}
```

Comment: hmm, you are using which browser?

Comment: firefox 3.6.15. Even the rich:editor has not been displayed if i add the above code.

Comment: thanks for reply. still i am getting null. here currentfr is coming as null. i can able to get the id of rich:editor but failed to fet the iframe id...

Comment: I am not familiar wich richfaces and jfs. If you are able to get the editors iframe it is easy to adjust what you need

Comment: i am using richFaces V3.3.3 and jsf 1.2